# How do I inject Identity classes with Ninject?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to use UserManager in a class, but I'm getting this error:

```
Error activating IUserStore{ApplicationUser}
No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable.
```

I'm using the default Startup.cs, which sets a single instance per request:

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
```

I'm able to get the ApplicationDbContext instance, which I believe is getting injected by Owin (Is that true?):

```
public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private ApplicationDbContext context;

    public GenericRepository(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }
}
```

But I can't do the same with UserManager (It throws the error shown before):

```
public class AnunciosService : IAnunciosService
{
    private IGenericRepository<Anuncio> _repo;
    private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;

    public AnunciosService(IRepositorioGenerico<Anuncio> repo, ApplicationUserManager userManager)
    {
        _repo = repo;
        _userManager = userManager;
    }
}
```

The controller uses the UserManager like this:

```
public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _userManager = value;
        }
    }
```

I'm using ninject to inject my other classes, but how do I inject the UserManager with it's dependencies and avoid using it like that in my controllers?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I injected It like this

```
kernel.Bind<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>>().To<UserStore<ApplicationUser>>();
kernel.Bind<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>().ToSelf();
```

And now It's working as it should.

Comment: Nice solution. It's working on my side as well. Thanks.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you.  You should go ahead and accept this as the answer even though you answered your own question.

Comment: Do you happen to have a working code example?  I've been struggling with this for couple weeks now and can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

OP's answer didn't work for me, as I was using a custom `ApplicationUser` class that has `long` as a key instead of `string` .

Hence, I created a generic static method the would get the `OwinContext` from the current `HttpContext` and return the desired concrete implementation.

```
private static T GetOwinInjection<T>(IContext context) where T : class
{
            var contextBase = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
            return contextBase.GetOwinContext().Get<T>();
}
```

I then used `GetOwinInjection` method for injection like this:

```
kernel.Bind<ApplicationUserManager>().ToMethod(GetOwinInjection<ApplicationUserManager>);

kernel.Bind<ApplicationSignInManager>().ToMethod(GetOwinInjection<ApplicationSignInManager>);
```

If you are also using `IAuthenticationManger`, you should inject it like this:

```
kernel.Bind<IAuthenticationManager>().ToMethod(context =>
            {
                var contextBase = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
                return contextBase.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
            });
```

Comment: Well I'm really stuck, because my key IS a string and OP's answer also does not work, I get exactly the same exception.